# In matplotlib legend how to define number of columns in horizontal legend (ncol or ncols)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, code-documentation

I was having a difficult time fixing the display of a legend in one matplotlib figure, and then I noticed that maybe there is an incongruence in matplotlib documentation, or I am not searching in the right place.
In my code, I can only make a horizontal legend work if I define `ncol`, as in the following example from [matplotlib demo](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/pylab_examples/legend_demo3.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 1)

# Plot the lines y=x**n for n=1..4.
ax = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
for n in range(1, 5):
    plt.plot(x, x**n, label="n={0}".format(n))
plt.legend(loc="upper left", bbox_to_anchor=[0, 1],
           ncol=2, shadow=True, title="Legend", fancybox=True)
ax.get_legend().get_title().set_color("red")
```

However, also in [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/legend_api.html), they state that `ncols`(and not `ncol`) is the right parameter name.
I also tested with `alignment` parameter and I got the same error as if I use `ncols`: `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'alignment'`.

I'm not sure if this is an error or I am missing something here.
I'm using matplotlib 3.4.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have always used `ncol` without problems but you are correct. If you check on the documentation  of the latest version of matplotlib 3.6.0 indicates `ncols`, this realase is quite recent (**15 September 2022**) and indicates the rename of the parameter [(release update)](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_3.6.0.html#ncol-keyword-argument-to-legend-renamed-to-ncols).  Nevertheless, probably both arguments are currently valid, since the last parameter defined in the function is still `ncol`.
[image]

For me it seems as `ncol` parameter will be deprecated in the future and `ncols` will be the only one used.

Notice that the parameter names change within versions of the packages. if you check older versions of [matplotlib 3.2.0](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/api/legend_api.html) `ncol` was the parameter defined.

Comment: Yes, you're probably right. But the problem is that if I use `ncols`I get an error (the same as if I use `alignment`), so for me it seems that only the "old" parameters are correct. This is a little bit strange...

Comment: @MrT77, I have added in the last update of the answer that the latest release of version is from 15 September 2022. Maybe you are still having an older version installed? I will suggest to try to upgrade matplotlib. Also if you are using conda, it might be the case that the latest version is still not available

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm still using 3.4.3. Thanks